# Llvm 10 error: Invalid record with void function

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm breaking my mind on my problem with a micro compiler wrote with the llvm and OCaml binding.
During the code generation function of my program, I have the error `error: Invalid record` from `llc` when I'm trying to compile a program that has some function with void type. However, it works well with all function with int type (my language support the only int).

This is a program that with LLC I have `error: Invalid record`

```
; ModuleID = 'MicrocC-module'
source_filename = "MicrocC-module"

declare i32 @print(i32)

declare i32 @getint()

define void @printem(i32 %0, i32 %1, i32 %2, i32 %3) {
entry:
  %a = alloca i32
  store i32 %0, i32* %a
  %b = alloca i32
  store i32 %1, i32* %b
  %c = alloca i32
  store i32 %2, i32* %c
  %d = alloca i32
  store i32 %3, i32* %d
  %acc_var = load i32, i32* %a
  %print = call i32 @print(i32 %acc_var)
  %acc_var1 = load i32, i32* %b
  %print2 = call i32 @print(i32 %acc_var1)
  %acc_var3 = load i32, i32* %c
  %print4 = call i32 @print(i32 %acc_var3)
  %acc_var5 = load i32, i32* %d
  %print6 = call i32 @print(i32 %acc_var5)
  ret void
}

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %printem = call void @printem(i32 42, i32 17, i32 192, i32 8)
  ret i32 0
}
```

and this is the program with all int functions, and it works without error

```
; ModuleID = 'MicrocC-module'
source_filename = "MicrocC-module"

declare i32 @print(i32)

declare i32 @getint()

define i32 @add(i32 %0, i32 %1) {
entry:
  %a = alloca i32
  store i32 %0, i32* %a
  %b = alloca i32
  store i32 %1, i32* %b
  %acc_var = load i32, i32* %a
  %acc_var1 = load i32, i32* %b
  %tmp = add i32 %acc_var, %acc_var1
  ret i32 %tmp
}

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %a = alloca i32
  %add = call i32 @add(i32 39, i32 3)
  store i32 %add, i32* %a
  %acc_var = load i32, i32* %a
  %print = call i32 @print(i32 %acc_var)
  ret i32 0
}
```

My LLVM version is the 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer and the solution is really stupid, but I want to add an answer because some new people on LLVM can have the same problem.

as in all language does not make sense store a result on a void function, in fact, in the main of my function there is the following code

```
%add = call i32 @add(i32 39, i32 3)
```

When a function is a Void the system call in OCaml, and I think also in C++ needs an empty string as a name function (in C++ I think it is null).
So the correct call is without the name %add.

In addition, I don't know why during the Ocaml build I received the `error: Invalid record` error, but I download the last version of LLVM [from github](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-11.0.1) and run directly the llvm compiler (llc), It has given me a very well description of the error, such as

```
./llc: error: ./llc: /media/vincent/VincentHDD/SandBoxDev/test_llvm.ll:35:3: error: instructions returning void cannot have a name
  %printem = call void @printem.1(i32 42, i32 17, i32 192, i32 8)
  ^
```